# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un dato en concreto de la base de datos en mi sitio usando php?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, aplicación-web

me gustaría aprender a acceder a un dato específico de mi base de datos y poderlo mostrar dentro de mi sitio web. Sé como mostrar todos los datos de una tabla, pero no conozco la manera de mostrar un solo dato en concreto. Desde ya, agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. La pregunta es muy ambigua. Además, evita evitar etiquetas no relacionadas (por ejemplo, phpmyadmin nada tiene que ver con la pregunta, y "aplicación-web" es una _meta-etiqueta_). Pegale una leída además al [centro de ayuda](/help).

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la respuesta a mi propia pregunta jajaja. A menos de una hora de publicarla. Pero bueno, por si a alguien más le pueda también servir entonces aquí está.

La respuesta es muy simple: con la palabra reservada de SQL `WHERE`, solo eso se necesita para traer los datos.

Desde mi tabla yo tenía esto:

```
$tabla = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
```

solo faltaba colocarle esto:

```
$tabla = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = 1";
```

y ya con eso me muestra solo los datos correspondientes a la primera fila y no los datos de todas las filas.

Si quieren cambiar de forma más dinámica la fila que quieren mostrar entonces coloquen una variable en lugar del 1, así:

```
$tabla = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = $id_number";
```

Comment: Hola, para futuras preguntas procura colocar el codigo que has intentado y la logica que quieres lograr, ya que esto no se consideraria una respuesta al ser de algo que simplemente no buscaste antes de preguntar